# Jenkins not building Jasper reports files

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

When i build my application with maven on eclipse, Run as -> maven install, the generated war file comes with the jasper files inside the package.
The problem is when i build with jenkins the war file come without the jasper (.jrxml/.jasper) files inside the package, only .class files. My jenkins job runs the same maven install command.

Anyone has a solution for this?

I already checked if the jasper files are on the git repository and they are.

Answer (score 0):

Issued resolved by adding

```
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.jasper</include>
                <include>**/*.jrxml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

to pom.xml